# Get random colour from list and convert to color name in Text widget

Tags: flutter, dart, colors

I'm making an app for my nephew for my own learning too. One screen uses a [package](https://pub.dev/packages/random_color) to generate random colours for me. There are 3 containers in a row each generating a random colour through a function `getRandomColor()` which generates 3 colours from a list. I later reference the index of the list to fill the container colours.

I have a text widget at the top of a column which contains a variable `randomChosenColor` which needs to display one of the colours from the list contained in `getRandomColor()`. I will use the math package to generate a random number between 1-3 which would fetch index 0-2 in `getRandomColor()`. I later plan on adding a gesture detecture to the containers to detect if the correct container is tapped if it equals the variable `randomChosenColor`.

Full code below. I'm new to flutter and this is my basic means of putting it together - please advise if there is a more efficient/cleaner method.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:random_color/random_color.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //

    List<Color> getRandomColor() {
      return [
        RandomColor().randomColor(),
        RandomColor().randomColor(),
        RandomColor().randomColor()
      ];
    }

    String randomChosenColor = ;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Choose the colour $randomChosenColor',
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  color: getRandomColor()[0],
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  color: getRandomColor()[1],
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  color: getRandomColor()[2],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getColorNameFromColor(yourColor).getName` method to get the name. This is provided by `random_color` package.
I am using List instead of method.

```dart
randomChosenColor =
    getColorNameFromColor(yourColor).getName;
```

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final randomColor = RandomColor();

  late List<Color> getRandomColor = [
    randomColor.randomColor(),
    randomColor.randomColor(),
    randomColor.randomColor()
  ];

  String? randomChosenColor;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Choose the colour $randomChosenColor',
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                for (int i = 0; i < getRandomColor.length; i++)
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      randomChosenColor =
                          getColorNameFromColor(getRandomColor[i]).getName;
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: 100,
                      width: 100,
                      color: getRandomColor[i],
                    ),
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```